# When using geth to synchronize with ligthouse, the ligthouse client reports the "Failed to get remote head and new block ranges: EndpointError"

Tags: synchronization

[image]

When using geth to synchronize with ligthouse, the ligthouse client reported the error "Failed to get remote head and new block ranges: EndpointError(FarBehind), retry_millis: 60000, service: deposit_contract_rpc". I checked the lighthouse documentation and found that geth is required to execute the client correctly. Start and synchronize, you can solve the problem, as shown below:
[image]
But there is a post in github with the same problem. The author said that geth will not be synchronized until lighthouse is synchronized. I don’t understand the relationship between this?
[image]
The solution given by the author is to delete the existing Lighthouse beacon node database. I tried it, but I still get this error. What exactly does this database refer to? At which location?

I was able to synchronize normally, but due to the abnormal shutdown of the server, I kept getting this error when I started synchronizing again.